# _fatalErrorMessageNeverStaticString Crash at a closing brace

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, fatal-error

I have 198 crashes on Crashlytics for one issue and i cant seem to figure it out, the last last line of my code that it points to is a closing brace, i understand that the problem is somewhere else in the code, but i dont seem to understand the Error message as i cant find anything about it on the internet. Has anyone experienced anything related to `_fatalErrorMessageNeverStaticString`.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1024731b8 _fatalErrorMessageNeverStaticString (__hidden#23281_:179)
1  MyAppName                      0x1010b95dc DetailTableViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () (DetailTableViewController.swift:124)
2  MyAppName                      0x1010b99c0 @objc DetailTableViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () (DetailTableViewController.swift)
3  UIKit                          0x18bb25a00 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1040
4  UIKit                          0x18bb255d8 -[UIViewController view] + 28
.
.
.
```

Comment: In your code, do you have a method called `faltaErrorMessageNeverStaticString`? If yes, could you show us the content of that method maybe?

Comment: No i dont have any method with that name. Its the error that the stack trace gives

Comment: OK, then what happens in your `viewDidLoad` method, that must be whats causing the crash

Comment: The immediate last thing i do in my code is an else part of a condition where i post a notification with `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: Keys.RECENT_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION), object: nil)`

Comment: OK, and no force unwrapping of optionals anywhere in your `viewDidLoad`? If you could please show us your `viewDidLoad` code, it would make things easier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, pbodsk did point me in the right direction. It was an Optional Unwrapping. In Fabric, i clicked `View all Sessions` and then with the switch turned to Keys, it showed me the correct crash log at the top of the usual crash logs.

The `_fatalErrorMessageNeverStaticString` message wasnt clear which threw me off but to my understanding it was that Fabric wasnt clear about the Crash Info Entry or it thought there were multiple different messages. But the solution was the View all Sessions to see the correct log.